# Transitions within magnetic sub levels: evaporative cooling to Bose Einstein Condensation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, bose-einstein-condensate, cold-atoms

Consider a Ioffe-Pritchard trap geometry.

Evaporative cooling works by decreasing the trap depth to remove atoms which are more energetic than average; this leads to cooling. This is done by using RF radiation to flip atoms from trapped states ($m_F>0$) to untrapped states ($m_F\leq 0$). My question is about these transitions and the selection rules. The alkalis from which BECs are formed are quasi single electron atoms therefore we expect the single electron jump condition $\Delta l=\pm 1$ to mean that these transitions ($|F,m_F\rangle\rightarrow|F,m_F'\rangle$) are not dipole allowed. Is this the case? Are we, by saying that such transitions can occur, outside of the realm of Russel-Saunders coupling?

Comment: It's a very long time ago, but isn't this a magnetic transition?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not quote the $\ell$ selection rules but the $F$ and $m_F$ ones, see below.

This is an adaptation from the [wikipedia table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule#Summary_table):
[image]

So the $\Delta m_F = \pm 1$ transitions *are* allowed.

What you should *really* be asking is how are these transitions allowed within the **same principal quantum number n**, so that parity is unchanged?

*Electric* dipole transitions of this type would be forbidden, but *magnetic* ones are allowed.

RF/MW evaporation use magnetic transitions.